# Can I save the Primarch's son on Tuchanka?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is it possible to save Primarch Victus's son? I've done the Turian bomb mission that Cerberus is trying to blow, and the son always end up dead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unfortunately Tarquin Victus cannot be saved.

Answer (score 2):

No, I have tried several times, and he cannot be saved.